# Expandable Search Box

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make my Search Box expand to the left, but I haven't been able to make it work, so any help on this issue will be really appreciated.

If you see any other mistake feel free to correct me and direct me in the right way to greatness.

```
<div class="search">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
```

look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLDCc/)

Comment: Do you want to increase the width to left or move it completely to the  left side of screen?

Comment: Here's a quick example for you [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Z7R57/)

Comment: For that matter its just where you placed it. Place it on the right and it will go left [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/FLDCc/2/)

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys that tried to help me out in this one. @Rudy I actually had it like before but change it because it didn't work but thanks to you I realize that I was missing a line, so Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

maybe :

add

```
right:0; to .search{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete search box

```
input {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}



input[type=search] {

    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 9px 10px 9px 10px;
    width: 55px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
    -moz-border-radius: 10em;
    border-radius: 10em;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 130px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #66CC75;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aps123/EH9HB/